# Mifare DESFire EV1 NFC tag for Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: android, nfc, samsung-mobile, mifare

Our Android app has the feature, launched by NFC Mifare DESFire EV1 tag and read the information. Every device is working fine, but it is not working for Samsung Galaxy S4.

If someone knows what the difference is, and how to launch Android app by NFC Mifare DESFire EV1 tag on Samsung Galaxy S4, please share. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, show some of your source code and/or AndroidManifest XML.

Comment: On the latest Samsung kernels for S4 something is broken. I had the same issue, and had to use ISO encapsulation to make it work again (native has... issues)

Answer (score 1):

Samsung changed their NFC chip this time (S4) so Mifare Classic is no longer supported. However I have here a Mifare DESfire EV1  and my S4 recognizes it correctly, also It does not recognize any mifare classic chip I have around here (1k || 4K)

Regards

(Model: SGH-M919, Android 4.2.2)